# parsing string value retrieved by firestore collection to firestore collection

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I had users stored in firestore collection under the path users.
i want that query get the data for a users depend on what I put for users.
i.e : I had a students and notification for different stages . if stage second. i retrieve second from getuser() fun then pars it to init() fun.  i had tried that but it shows that string value is null

```
    private void init() {
    Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("docs").orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<download> docsFirestoreRecyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<download>()
            .setQuery(query, download.class)
            .build();

    adapter = new FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<download, docViewHolder>(docsFirestoreRecyclerOptions) {
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final docViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull final download model) {
            //teacher, name, date, url;
            holder.teacher.setText(model.getTeacher());
            holder.name.setText(model.getName());
            holder.date.setText(model.getDate());
            holder.url.setText(model.getLink());
            holder.btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),R.string.under_dev, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });


            final String url = holder.url.getText().toString();
            holder.doc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   /* Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);*/


                    if (url.isEmpty()) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "this doesn't contains a link for download", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                    } else {
                        Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), otherUrl.class);
                        i.putExtra("URL", url);
                        v.getContext().startActivity(i);


                    }

                }
            });


        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public docViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.downloads, parent, false);
            return new docViewHolder(view);
        }
    };
}
public void checkuser() {
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        // Name, email address, and profile photo Url
        String name = user.getDisplayName();
        String email = user.getEmail();
        Uri photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl();
        boolean emailVerified = user.isEmailVerified();
        // The user's ID, unique to the Firebase project. Do NOT use this value to
        // authenticate with your backend server, if you have one. Use
        // FirebaseUser.getIdToken() instead.
        String uid = user.getUid();
        String userId = Objects.requireNonNull(mAuth.getCurrentUser()).getUid().toString();

        DocumentReference ref=firebaseFirestore.collection("users").document(userId);
        ref.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable DocumentSnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                assert value != null;

                // docView=value.getString("stage");
                textStage.setText(value.getString("stage"));

                getStage=value.getString("stage");


            }
        });


    }


}
```

[image: I want to pars this word "docs" in the top to use it instead of that in firestore document ref]

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, you are saying that you want to fire a query to select a particular user from the database. Is that true?
then

> String user - "uid12321";
> Query query = firebaseFirestore.collection("docs").collection(user);

Fire above query to get particular user.

Comment: thank you > the data that i want to retrieve are in firestore document reference  that named users.